# MySQL query | Select latest row from groups

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I have a table similar to this:

| product_id | client_id | category | price | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 3.1 | 2022-11-01 |
| 2 | 1 | A | 3.2 | 2022-11-02 |
| 3 | 1 | B | 3.3 | 2022-11-03 |
| 4 | 1 | B | 3.4 | 2022-11-04 |
| 5 | 2 | B | 3.5 | 2022-11-05 |
| 6 | 2 | B | 3.6 | 2022-11-06 |
| 7 | 2 | A | 3.7 | 2022-11-07 |
| 8 | 2 | C | 3.8 | 2022-11-08 |

And I want to select the price from the **latest** created_date from each client_id and category, so my expected result would be this:

| product_id | client_id | category | price | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | A | 3.2 | 2022-11-02 |
| 4 | 1 | B | 3.4 | 2022-11-04 |
| 6 | 2 | B | 3.6 | 2022-11-06 |
| 7 | 2 | A | 3.7 | 2022-11-07 |
| 8 | 2 | C | 3.8 | 2022-11-08 |

Could you please help me with this? Thanks

I found something similar here: [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

**UPDATE**

Actually I want to do the same with the following (this is a more realistic example): https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fHc6MafduyibJdkLHe9cva/0

Expected result:

| val1 | val2 | num1 | num2 | created_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| X | A | 33 | 333 | 2022-11-03 |
| X | B | 66 | 666 | 2022-11-06 |
| X | C | 88 | 888 | 2022-11-08 |
| X | D | 99 | 999 | 2022-11-09 |
| Y | A | 111 | 1111 | 2022-11-11 |

Answer (score 0):

You can do in this way.
Use MAX to get the latest date first and group by category and client ID.

Check out this [db_fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/g7yxeSQxEexF8Cw2sVqwfq/1)

```
SELECT a.pid, b.cid, b.category, a.price, b.created_date FROM products a
JOIN 
    (SELECT category, cid, MAX(created_date) as created_date FROM products GROUP BY cid, category) as b
    ON a.category = b.category AND a.cid = b.cid AND a.created_date = b.created_date
ORDER BY pid
```

Please provide DDL + DML commands next time when you ask question so that others don't need to prepare DDL and DML commands by their own. It is advisable to share what you've tried as well.

Comment: Thanks for your support, this is was I tried before asking: SELECT t1.product_id, t1.client_id, t1.category, t1.price, t1.created_date
FROM my_table AS t1
WHERE t1.created_date = (SELECT MAX(t2.created_date) FROM my_table AS t2 WHERE t1.product_id = t2.product_id)
GROUP BY t1.client_id, t1.category -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: can you pls update this in your question and share us the result of your query? Did you hit any error running your query?

Comment: @JohnP I believe you hit the error when you run this query. GROUP BY list should be the same as your selected columns. You selected product_id, client_id, category, price and created_date but you only group client_id and category? Please try out my solution

Answer (score 0):

written in postgresql standard. It may helpful for you.

```
select 
distinct
first_value(pid) over(w) as pid,
first_value(cid) over(w),
first_value(category) over(w),
first_value(price) over(w),
first_value(created_date) over(w)
from products
window  w as (partition by cid,category order by created_date desc)
```

Tested in Postgresql DB. it is working as expected.

Comment: His rdbms is mysql

Comment: it should work.. sql written in ANSI standard

Answer (score 0):

If your `MySQL` version is  **8.0** or higher,then we can use [**windows function**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) to do it

```
create table test_data(
product_id int,
client_id int,
category varchar(10),   
price float,
created_date date
);

insert into test_data(product_id,client_id,category,price,created_date) values
(1,1,'A',3.1,'2022-11-01'),
(2,1,'A',3.2,'2022-11-02'),
(3,1,'B',3.3,'2022-11-03'),
(4,1,'B',3.4,'2022-11-04'),
(5,2,'B',3.5,'2022-11-05'),
(6,2,'B',3.6,'2022-11-06'),
(7,2,'A',3.7,'2022-11-07'),
(8,2,'C',3.8,'2022-11-08');


SELECT t.*
FROM 
(SELECT *,
 row_number() over(PARTITION BY client_id,category order by created_date DESC)  as tn from test_data) as t
WHERE t.tn=1
order by t.product_id
```

[**DB Fiddle Demo**](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gM4onNTHkmfKbutQ1P7irM/0)